# Вывод значений из разных таблиц если в одной из таблицы

Tags: sql

Добрый день , столкнулся с такой задачей нужно вывести поля из 3 таблиц базы допустим a , b , c :

> SELECT a.field1 , b.field2, c.field3 FROM a, b , c WHERE a.id = 1

Если записи в таблице присутствует , то все нормально выводит , но если в одной из таблиц нету записи , то ничего не выводит. Так вот вопрос можно ли сделать такой запрос , что если в одной из таблиц нету подходящей записи выводило нулл

```
a.field1  b.field2 c.field3 

1           2         null

2           null       3
```

Или такое невозможно ?

Comment: какая СУБД у вас?

Comment: @teran MySQL , пока единственное решение в которое пришло в голову это при создание записи в основной таблицы А и генерировать записи в таблицы b , с со значением null . тогда он выведет более менее нормально , но это кажется не оч хорошим решением .

Comment: Юзайте или лефт джойн или юнион элл смотря какие данные и какая субд
SELECT a.field1 , b.field2, c.field3 FROM a
left join b on a.ключ=b.ключ
left join c on a.ключ=c.ключ
WHERE a.id = 1

Comment: А как связаны данные? Они вообще имеют связи? Т.е. каждому `a.id` соответствует 1 `b.id` и `c.id`?

Answer (score 1):

Использовать `JOIN'ы`:

```
SELECT a.field1, b.field2, c.field3 FROM a 
    LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id 
    LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id 
        WHERE a.id = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT a.field1, b.field2, c.field3 FROM a 
    RIGHT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id 
    RIGHT JOIN c ON a.id = c.id 
        WHERE a.id = 1
```

Вроде так